# Xml validation against multiple xsd

Tags: xsd, spring-integration

In Spring Integration pipeline we currently use the validating filter to validate xml message against a certain xsd schema.

```
<int-xml:validating-filter schema-location=classpath:/a.xsd />
```

It works fine when the xml has just one schema. What is the best approach when there are multiple schemas against which the xml should be validated?

E.g.

```
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn1" xsi:schemaLocation="urn1 urn1.xsd">
<Hdr> 
</Hdr>
<Pyld>
    <Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn2 urn2.xsd">
    </Document>
</Pyld>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the fact that there is an alternative attribute to configure for that `<int-xml:validating-filter>`:

```
                <xsd:attribute name="xml-validator" type="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            Reference to a custom 'org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidator' strategy
                        </xsd:documentation>
                        <xsd:appinfo>
                            <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                                <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidator"/>
                            </tool:annotation>
                        </xsd:appinfo>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:attribute>
```

And with that one you already can provide several XSD resource to include into validation. See a `XmlValidatorFactory` for more info.